# Convergence in distribution of $N(0, 1/n)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution

I am a graduate student in statistics and am self-studying convergence in probability.  I am a little confused on the following problem.

I am trying to follow a proof that claims
$$X_n\sim N(0,1/n) \overset{D}{\rightarrow} 0.$$

The proof uses the definition
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} F_n(t) = F(t)$$
to show the convergence in distribution, where $F(t)$ is c.d.f. of the point mass distribution at $0.$  The proof shows that, for $t<0$,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} F_n(t) = \mathbb{P}(X_n < t) = 0,$$
and that for $t>0$,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} F_n(t) = \mathbb{P}(X_n < t) =1.$$
The proof then concludes that $X_n \overset{D}{\rightarrow} 0.$

**My question:**

I completely understand the steps of the proof and how the limits were found, which is why I chose not to include them here.  I do *not* understand the last statement.  Wouldn't it be more correct to say that $X_n \overset{D}{\rightarrow} X$, where $X$ is the point mass distribution at $0$? The definition of convergence of distribution states that a random variable converges to *another random variable.*  $0$ is not a random variable.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you say that $0$ is not random variable? Random variables can have a single value in the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A random variable $X$ is a function $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$.

When we write $X=0$ as a random variable, this is just the function taking every point $\omega\in\Omega$ to $X(\omega) = 0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Note that this is different from the distribution of the random variable $0$, which *is* the point mass at zero.